# Efficient way to initialize larga, non-const Eigen Matrix

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have a 4000-by-4 matrix that needs to be initialized with different values.

I notice the following takes so much time in GCC that it virtually hangs up the compiler:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,1000,500> mat; 
mat.setZero();

mat << 1,2,3,4,
       10,2,3,1,
       (etc)
```

So, I thought I can also do this:

```
int i=0;
mat.row(i++) << 1,2,3,4;
mat.row(i++) << 10,2,3,1;
(etc)
```

Is there a more compiling-time and runtime-efficient way of doing this?

Comment: For such large matrices, better use a `MatrixXd` instead of a statically allocated one.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the values in a POD-array (possibly aligned) and use an `Eigen::Map` on that:

```
EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(32) // align if you want to use SIMD
static const // leave the const, if you want to modify the data
double data[4*4]  = {  // 4000*4 in your case
        0, 1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6, 7,
        8, 9,10,11,
        12,13,14,15,
        // ...
};
// again, leave the const, if you want to modify `mat`:
// RowMajor is easier to read when defining `data`
const static Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, Eigen::RowMajor>, Eigen::Aligned32> mat(data);
```

Comment: would Eigen allow ```mat``` to be assigned to a Eigen::Matrix?

Comment: @anr Yes, you can use an `Eigen::Map<...>` the same way as any other `Eigen::Matrix`